# How to map enum types to character arrays?

Tags: arrays, c++11, enums, char

I am TCP-IP communication over TCP.
I have specific packets to query and then I receive a response based on that. 
My packet is basically a character array that i convert to string like this:

```
unsigned char array1 []={0,132,0,0,0,6,84,5,0,1,255,0}; 
std::string load_seqInit ( array1, array1 + sizeof array1 / sizeof array1[0] );
```

However, I want to store these arrays separately as enum values. So that I can just call the enumtype and it will map to my respective array.

```
enum packets{
    LOAD,
    READ,
    RESET,
    UNLOAD      
}
```

So maybe when I call enum type LOAD it will point to the packet:

```
unsigned char array1 []={0,132,0,0,0,6,84,5,0,1,255,0};
```

then I can just convert the enum to string and proceed with my query and response.

Answer (score 0):

If the arrays are 8 bytes in size you could do:

```
class enum packets : unsigned long {
    LOAD = 0x1234567812345678, // the hex representation of the array
    ...
}
```

If they're not, you could go with a more naive implementation using an `std::map<packets, array[]>` that maps from an enum value to array.

Comment: My array is 12 bytes. Any link suggestion that I can look up to for the mapping  @ytoledano